# Safe to allow users to save HTML to the database?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have a site that my customers can use to allow their customers to register online (this is for daycare registrations).  So I provide this online registration form and allow my customers to customize the "thank you" message that is displayed after the registration is complete.

Is it safe to allow my customers to use HTML to format their thank you message?  I know this would allow them to also generate javascript but should I care about that?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely should care if you don't want to expose your users to a [cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability.

Comment: You should absolutely care. Ask OWASP for why and how. Also, it's rather easy to prevent, and at the same time allow people to use angle brackets without escaping them (which non-technical users won't, I promise)... provided you have a bit of discipline and are using a technology which helps with it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you most certainly should care.

```
<img src="http://evil.com/evilScript.js">
```

on their thank you message, I'll leave what could be on `evilScript.js` to your imagination.

---

My suggestion, use Markdown as a format, and parse it to HTML when you need it (in the View).

Comment: +1 I was just writing this very thing. I would use a simplified version of Markdown that doesn't support embedding HTML, otherwise you have the same problem, only with nicer syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe--as long as you sanitize it to some degree. A great example is to use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and only allow things like `<h1>`, `<h2>`, `<b>`, `<u>` etc. tags but avoid `<script>`, `<object>` and other dangerous tags.

*I know I'm referencing a PHP method, but a lot of languages have this kind of functionality to cleanse user input. Take it at face-value and not making this a PHP-specific answer.*

Comment: `strip_tags` provides a blacklist, where he would need a whitelist. You could do it with a blacklist, but that's not optimal.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Indeed. I use it as an e.g. not as a benchmark for security. But indeed, implement a method of white-listing explicit tags and, if you've developed the solution yourself, **test thoroughly**.